# How to fix File Load Error for markdown file in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I get the following error when I try to open *.md file as a notebook in JupyterLab:
`File file_name.md is in format/version=markdown/1.2 (current version is 1.1). It would not be safe to override the source of file_name.md with that file. Please remove one or the other file.`

I understand from *.md and the error message that the given markdown uses 1.2 version of format (`format_version: '1.2'`). However, I don't understand what I should do to update it. I use poetry virtual environment. I tried to reinstall the environment to get last markdown/jupytext versions but to no success.

`poetry show` gives me `markdown=="3.2.1"` and `jupytext==1.3.0`. How to update the used format version to be able to open new markdown files?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message.

```
pip3 install jupytext --upgrade
```

updates the jupytext version. Then, I was able to open the file.